# How do I reference an specific hard drive on Windows?

Tags: windows, eclipse, git, portability, egit

I'm trying to configure EGit on my portable Eclipse app.
I needed then to install PortableGit on my USB drive as well.

After that I'm trying to reference the System Setting from the Eclipse's Preferences.
The way that I can manage this is to set it to 'G:\programs\PortableGit-1.7.10-preview20120409\etc\gitconfig'

The problem is that when I use this on a different system my USB might not be in G:.

Perhaps there is another way to determine Windows' drives names by the UUID or something else, does anybody know anything about it?

Alternatively I would use a relative path. Assuming that eclipse is in 'G:\programs\eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-win32\eclipse\eclipse.exe' it should work with '..\..\PortableGit-1.7.10-preview20120409\etc\gitconfig', right? But turns out it doesn't. It sets itself to the full path.

I'm pretty lost here. Why is it not as simple as /media/USBdrive?

Comment: Is your workspace and your git repo on your USB stick as well?

Comment: @PaulWebster yes, they are both on my stick

Comment: @svnpenn sorry about that, I meant specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could launch Eclipse from the drive using a script that sets up PATH so the git executable is in it. Then Eclipse will find Git on startup and deduce $prefix from that.